# Highlighting input box when selected using meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I'm learning meteor. I'm trying to adapt an application that i've created using only html, css and javascript to meteor.js framework just for learning purposes. But i'm having problem making this code work using the meteor framework. Do I need to use a helper to select the email class then change this using javascript?

Sorry if it's a silly question, but i spent all day searching and i wasn't able to find out by myself.

The code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="E-mail" class="email-inactive" onFocus="toggleText(this);" onBlur="toggleText(this);">
```

JS

```
    var toggleText = function (el)
{
    var v = el.value;

   //Remove text to allow editing
    if(v=="E-mail") {
        el.value = "";
        el.className = "email-active";
    }
    else {
         //Remove whitespace
        if(v.indexOf(" ")!=-1) {
            split = v.split(" ").join("");
            v = split;
        }

          //Change to inactive state
        if(v=="") {
            el.value = "E-mail";
            el.className = "email-inactive";
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.email-active {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.79);
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-color: #2980b9;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.email-active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.email-inactive {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 300;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.26);
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to replace classes with events instead of helpers

```
Template.emailTemplate.events({
  'focus #email':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(event.target).removeClass('email-inactive').addClass('email-active')
  },
  'focusout #email':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(event.target).removeClass('email-active').addClass('email-inactive')
  }
});
```